# Output of this program

Tags: c, error-handling, signals

What direction does this program take? I'm having a hard time following `x`.

```
int x = 10;

void handler(sig) {

    x += 7;
    return;

}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    int pid;
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler); 
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        x -= 3;
        exit(0); 
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); 
    printf("x = %d\n", x); 
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could compile and execute it?

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific about which part of the program you don't understand. For example, do you understand `fork`? Do you understand `signal`? etc. Which parts don't you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What direction does this program take? I'm having a hard time
>   following x.

To illustrate whats going on here, we can add another call to `printf()`, where the child process executes:

```
int pid;
signal(SIGCHLD, handler); 
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    x -= 3;
    printf("x = %d\n", x); 
    exit(0); 
}
```

What is happenning inside this program, step by step:

You setup your signal handler to execute when the child process will end: `signal(SIGCHLD, handler)`.

By writing `if ((pid = fork()) == 0)`, you are executing section under if as code for child (as you compare fork result to `0`). Moreover, forked process inherits the value of `10`, which by the time we execute child process's code is equal to `10`. Then we subtract `3` from `10`:

```
int pid;
signal(SIGCHLD, handler); 
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    x -= 3;
    printf("x = %d\n", x); 
    exit(0); 
}
```

But **it only happens in the child process**, therefore when you execute the last part of your code:

```
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); 
printf("x = %d\n", x);
```

then the handler is being executed (in the parent process), therefore adding `7` to `10` (value of x in the parent process). This is why at the end you get `17`.